# Collapsible member events in Visual Studio designer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, designer, windows-forms-designer

How can I get my control members to show their events on the Visual Studio event grid? Visual Studio does this for certain things like the "(DataBindings)" member by putting them in a collapsible section, like so:

[collapsible events in visual studio http://tseqkw.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pD-vBYTm53aShasVJk9nh0JY_8bHkp9jH5cfGaSDKZwDXmlF4WJzPqO8GuH2jhY2A6cy2wDGv5Pr42Z-KOG96YA/collapse-events.png](http://tseqkw.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pD-vBYTm53aShasVJk9nh0JY_8bHkp9jH5cfGaSDKZwDXmlF4WJzPqO8GuH2jhY2A6cy2wDGv5Pr42Z-KOG96YA/collapse-events.png)

I'd like to do this for some of my own components, since their events are usually handled on the form, and having to create handlers manually is annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to implement a TypeConverter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx